# How to push different view to stack view using a function in qml main file

Tags: qt, qml

working on an application using qml for the interface. I have a stack view in the main qml file which will push the qml file which will be a page to the stack view. Because there are multiple pages and buttons in these pages that when clicked may push a different page onto the stack view, I created a function in the main qml file which i will call from the pages  when buttons are clicke. The pages folder which contain many different pages is a subdirectory of main.qml folder. The functionis supposed to push the pages unto the stack view. However, on click of the button, the satck view does not push the new page.

This is the code below

main qml file

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtQuick.Window 2.15
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import "pages"



Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    property url source: ""

    function changeView(source){
        stackView.push(Qt.resolvedUrl(source))
    }

    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#391199"
        anchors.fill: parent

        StackView {
            id: stackView
            anchors.fill: parent
            initialItem: Qt.resolvedUrl("pages/homepage.qml")
        }
    }
}

/*##^##
Designer {
    D{i:0;formeditorZoom:0.75}
}
##^##*/
```

homePage.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import "qrc:../main.qml" as Main

Item {
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#08630f"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            id: button
            x: 478
            y: 255
            text: qsTr("Change ")
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 10
            onClicked: {
                source = "pages/nextPage.qml"
                Main.changeView(source)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

nextPage.qml

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.15
import "../main.qml" as Main

Item {
    Rectangle {
        id: rectangle
        color: "#08404b"
        anchors.fill: parent

        Button {
            id: button
            x: 478
            y: 255
            text: qsTr("Change ")
            anchors.right: parent.right
            anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
            anchors.rightMargin: 10
            anchors.bottomMargin: 10
            onClicked: {
                Main.changeView("pages/homePage.qml")
            }
        }
    }

}
```

I suspect the problem is coming from the calling of the function but i have a little expertise in qml. I get this error: Property 'changeView' of object [object Object] is not a function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will want to call the `changeView` function on the actual main window, not on the import.

This involves a bit of "magic", you can give the main `Window` an id, which will be available in all the children of it (so, magic because if looking at a single page file, you can wonder what that id is doing there). So, make sure to pick a wise name which won't collide with other id (i.e. `root` would be quite bad)

```
//main.qml
Window {
    id: main_window

    function changeView(source) { ... }
}

//homePage.qml
Item {
    ...

    Button {
        ...
        onClicked: main_window.changeView("pages/nextPage.qml")
    }
}
```

Comment: I know this answers the question, but this is quite bad to do. Every component which uses `main_window` globally like this is not reusable in any other context.